# how to select N items each time from database(mysql or mongodb)?

Tags: python, mysql, mongodb, generator

Case1:Mysql,pymysql

The code block shows below will generate a generator, how could get N items from database and send them to some function with multithreading.For example, each time I want to select 10k items from database, and the total items is 100million, so the total count will be 100million / 10k = 10k.

```
cursor.execute(sql)
for result in cursor:
     yield result
```

Case2:Mongodb,pymongo

```
for result in db.find():
  yield result
```

Generator is a function that saves lots of memory when the database has large set of data.

What I've tried is itertool.islice, but it just return the first N items of generator. So for these two case, do you have any better solution to select N items each time? Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Use limit 10000 * ({page} - 1), 10000 in sql.
For mongo, use cursor's function skip and limit as well.

Then you can get 10k docs in batch in each loop.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,  could you make it more clear?